# MongoDB perormance issues with geoNear

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey I have a MongoDB database and I'm using Node.js with Mongoose.

I have a collection which mongoose schema looks like this:

```
{
    location2d: {
        type: [Number],  //[<longitude>, <latitude>]
        index: '2dsphere'
    },
    name: String,
    owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player', index: true},
}
```

This collection is quite big (500'000 documents). When I do a simple nearest find query, it runs quite fast ~10 ms.

But when I do something like this:

```
this.find({owner: {$ne:null}})
        .where('location2d')
        .near({center: [center.lon, center.lat], maxDistance: range / 6380000, spherical: true})
        .limit(10)
        .select('owner location2d')
        .exec()
```

it takes a very long time, about 60 seconds! Just because I added `{owner: {$ne:null}}` in the `find` method multiplies the times required to perform by 6000.

What am I doing wrong? How can I improve this?

When I do a search by owner it's fast, when I do a search by proximity it's fast but when I combine both it's unbelievably slow.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a solution, a little bit dirty but very fast.

1st: create a new field called `ownerIdAsInt` which is the int parsed of the owner mongo Id : `document.ownerIdAsInt = parseInt(document.owner.toString(), 16)`. If `owner` is null, set that field to 0

2nd: Define a compound index with `{ownerIdAsInt: 1, location2d: "2dsphere"}`

Your schema should like like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    location2d: {
        type: [Number],  //[<longitude>, <latitude>]
        index: '2dsphere'
    },
    name: String,
    owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player', index: true},
    ownerIdAsInt: Number
});
schema.index({ownerIdAsInt: 1, location2d: "2dsphere"});
```

and the query now is:

```
this.find({ownerIdAsInt: {$gt: 0},
        location2d: {$nearSphere: [center.lon, center.lat],
            $maxDistance: range / 6380000}})
    .limit(10)
    .select('owner location2d')
    .exec()
```

Result are now ~20 ms long. Much faster!